# Can anyone help me with aligning a icon by CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am unable to align this icon with others by CSS,
[image]

Can anyone one help me with aligning this? The page link is https://merchla.my/my-account/
TIA.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards please [edit] your question to add a [mre]!

Comment: @0stone0 I think I have added all the minimal reproducible elements. Can you point what I may have added?

Comment: You're missing the code that creates your minimum reproducible example, linking to your website is not acceptable because once you fix the problem then no other user in the future has a practicable example to work with.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this class here `<ul class="jssocials-shares" id="wpuf_social_link">` add `display: flex;`

Comment: np. like others pointed out, in the future you have to add your actual code though.

Comment: Sure. I will. I was in a hurry actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ul.jssocials-shares li.jssocials-share-google a img {
     width: auto;
    height: 1em;
```

Remove all the css code from below code

```
ul.jssocials-shares li.jssocials-share-google a { }
```